# Agregar escuchador que revise constantemente un valor

Tags: android, kotlin

Quiero limitar el número de fichas que se pueden agregar a mi aplicación en función del número de fichas que se hayan añadido, ya realiza esa función pero sólo tiene en cuenta el valor de nombres al iniciar la aplicación en lugar de hacerlo cada vez que agrego una ficha, ¿Cómo podría implementar un escuchador que realice dicha función a partir del siguiente código? Gracias.

```
db.collection(coleccionFichas).addSnapshotListener { snapShot, _ ->
        
        val nombres = snapShot?.documents?.map {
            val ficha = Ficha()
            ficha.id = it.id
        }?.toTypedArray()
        nombres?.let {
            adaptador.dataSet = it
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        if (nombres?.count()!! >= 7) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Has alcanzado el número máximo de fichas para la versión gratuita",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            buttonNewCar.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Has alcanzado el número máximo de fichas para la versión gratuita",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No entendí muy bien la redacción, pero puedes crear un observador (observable) de la siguiente manera:

```
private val numFichas: Int by Delegates.Observable(/*initial value*/){_, oldValue, newValue ->
/*TODO WHEN VALUE CHANGE*/
}
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/346334)